# Programmatically highlight combobox item

Tags: wpf, combobox, highlight

Is there any way to highlight comboboxitem programmatically?

Property IsHighlighted has no setter((. Changing style is not enought.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to select rather than highlight (the IsHighlighted property is used to indicate a selected item), you can just set the `IsSelected` property or the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` of the parent ComboBox.