# Programmatically Highlighting MenuItem.Items

Tags: wpf

Working with System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem
[image: Programmatically HighLighting MenuItem]

Can Highlighting specific MenuItems be done in code?
The solution response provided **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196026/1699071)**(*for a clearer picture* [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/2046451.aspx)) cannot be applied as `Controls.MenuItem` doesn't have property `IsSelected` & the `set` accessor for `IsHighlighted` is protected - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ishighlighted(v=vs.110).aspx).

The corresponding MenuItem in Windows.Forms has a `PerformSelect()` method.
But integrating it to WPF doesn't seem possible. Following example: [from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var menuitem = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
var wfHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();  
wfHost.Child = menuitem;  
this.changeCountriesMenuItem.Items.Add(menuitem);
```

The above doesn't work as assigning `wfHost.Child` is invalid:

> "Cannot convert from Forms.MenuItem to Forms.Control"

Comment: you may perhaps override the style and achieve something similar.

Answer (score 3):

With direction from [@pushpraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612760/pushpraj)
Created Custom MenuItem
& implemented my own method:

```
public class CustomMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public void PerformMyOwnHighLight()
    {
        base.IsHighlighted = true;
    }
}
```

That simple.
With `protected` set accessor as Hint. Guess I'm not as proficient in OO concepts as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SAm for getting me started on this. Here's a bindable version. Notice I use a property IsSelected to differentiate between that and highlighting, even though they are both the same thing:

```
public class HighlightableMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsSelected), typeof(bool), typeof(HighlightableMenuItem),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, IsSelectedPropertyChanged));

    private static void IsSelectedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = d as HighlightableMenuItem;

        if(menuItem != null)
        {
            menuItem.IsHighlighted = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); 
        set => SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); 
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks straightforward, but: how do I get the ContextMenu to use my custom MenuItem class, if the menu is populated via binding? Is overriding ContextMenu.GetContainerForItemOverride safe? Exactly mimicking the base class' behavior does not seem possible, because it uses some private members...